# How to show that a number is an algebraic Integer

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Show that $[\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}+ 1]/3$

My attempt is this:

Set it equal to x, multiply both sides by 3, and subtract both sides by 1. Then I cube both sides. However, I am stuck after that. Here's my math below:

$$x=[\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}+ 1]/3$$
$$\implies 3x=\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}+ 1$$
$$\implies3x-1=\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}$$
$$\implies(3x - 1)^3 = (\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10})^3$$
$$\implies27x^3 - 27x^2 + 9x - 1 = 110 + 3(\root3\of{100})^2(\root3\of{10}) + 3(\root3\of{100})(\root3\of{10})^2$$

If I were to factor the right hand side, then I would get $110 + 3(\root3\of{100})(\root3\of{10})[\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}]$. If I were to cube both again, then my right hand side would have something like that. Help would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos, I am pretty much new to math stack exchange and I apologize if my question looks sloppy.

Comment: Find its minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$ (a cubic), and check whether the coefficients of that polynomial are integers. That's all there is to it. A surefire way of finding the minimal polynomial is to write $1,x,x^2$ and $x^3$ in terms of the basis $\{1,\root3\of{10},\root3\of{100}\}$ and solve the coefficients $a,b,c$ from the linear system resulting from
$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0.$$

Comment: $x^3-x^2-3x-3$.

Comment: A trick way is to observe that $1+\root3\of{10}+\root3\of{100}$ is, by the geometric sum formula, equal to $(1-10)/(1-\root3\of{10})$. This lets you find the minimal polynomial using that of $1-\root3\of{10}$ and the reciprocal.

Comment: That would definitely change my math. Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen for showing me this!

Comment: I got it the answer:

1/27 * x^3 + 1/3 * x^2 + x - 9= 0

Comment: @bgj123 "*then I would get...*" $\;-\;$ Hint: $\;110 + 3\underbrace{(\root3\of{100})(\root3\of{10})}_{\displaystyle =\, 10}[\underbrace{\root3\of{100} + \root3\of{10}}_{\displaystyle=\,3x-1}]\,$.

Comment: The algebra looks much simpler if you avoid writing radicals and just use $a=\sqrt[3]{10}, a^3=10$ and the number in question is $b=(1+a+a^2)/3$.

Comment: The algebraic integer in question is part of an integral basis of $K=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt [3]{10})$, the basis being $\{1,a,b\} $ where $a, b$ are as in my previous comment.

Comment: The general question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/250484/11619). See also [this related example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3465093/11619). [More discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445333/11619).

Answer (score 6):

The number
$$x=\frac{1+\root3\of{10}+\root3\of{100}}3=\frac3{\root3\of10-1}$$
by the formula for a geometric sum (or by $a^2+ab+b^2=(a^3-b^3)/(a-b)$).

- The minimal polynomial of $\root3\of{10}$ is $f(T)=T^3-10$.
- Therefore the minimal polynomial of $\root3\of{10}-1$ is
  $$g(T):=f(T+1)=T^3+3T^2+3T-9.$$
- Therefore $1/(\root3\of{10}-1)$ is a zero of the reciprocal polynomial
  $$h(T):=T^3 g(1/T)=1+3T+3T^2-9T^3.$$
- Therefore $x$ is a zero of the polynomial
  $$m(T):=-3h(T/3)=-3-3T-T^2+T^3.$$

This is monic and has integer coefficients. The claim follows.

Comment: The exact same calculation works for the general interesting case of $\root3\of{m}$, $m\equiv1\pmod9$ in place of $m=10$. Somehow I had avoided seeing this approach before, banal as it is. Or it only made it into my subconscious? Live and learn, I suppose :-)